# Passing a value from Page_Load to Form with POST

Tags: asp.net

I'm really new to ASP and have a project where I need to capture the login of the person logged into Sharepoint.  I have created the following code and am able to get the login.  I am having trouble pass the parameter to a form.  What is the best way to do this:  I know the 2nd part the POST is wrong,  I don't know what to do here.  Thanks for your help.  Scott

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    string userName = "NA";

userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    string userWithoutDomain = userName.Substring(userName.IndexOf('\\') + 1);

    myuserid.Text = userWithoutDomain;
    }
</script>


<html>
<body>


<form method="POST" action="http://srs.xxx.edu:9001/signon/authenticate.asp" id="myuserid" name="myuserid">

    <input type="hidden" name="COOKIEPATH" value="/SRS/">


    <input style="width:70px;font-size:8pt;" size="8" name="myuserid" >
    <input style="width:70px;font-size:8pt;" size="8" name="myuserid" >

    <input class="button" type="submit" value=" Log On " style="display:none;">

 </form>

  <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:label id="myuserid" runat="server" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values from the codebehind to html page using for example hidden values, see [here](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/26184).

Usually though values are placed into form elements in the codebehind directly.  If the element has the "runat=server" attribute then you can access the element in the Page_Load method using c# and just set the text value directly.

myuserid.Text =